# Can't run newly created angular project through angular-cli due to access forbidden issues

Tags: angular

[image]

I am getting this error whenever I try to run my newly created angular project. What's causing this? I've searched everywhere and I am out of ideas. I created my project through the use of the latest angular-cli.

`VM953:1 GET http://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/forton/cbp/cmps/50_c211e.js`

EDIT: This is highly because of browser extension. Lesson learned.Nothing to do with Angular!

Comment: From the very little information that you have provided I can say that is not Angular or angular-cli error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be caused by a browser extension and not by Angular. Try disabling them one by one.

Comment: You seem to be correct. Man, thank you. What a silly question!